# Looking for geocoded survey data of households and individuals

Tags: data-request, geospatial, survey

I am looking for open datasets with survey data of households and individuals which includes the location of the survey respondents in coordinates. The datasets should be worldwide or covering at least areas exceeding single counties or small (sub-)continents.
For example, the Demographic & Health Surveys (DHS) collect survey data in 90 countries that provide information on a wide range of monitoring and impact evaluation indicators in the areas of population, health, and nutrition. Most of the surveys also include the location of households in small clusters of around 20 to 30 households. Now I am looking for alternatives of the DHS data.

Comment: hi, i doubt many geocoordinates are public due to respondent confidentiality..